# Rearranging information on spreadsheet using Google Apps Script arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Been dealing with this code for a couple of days now. What I want to achieve in the spreadsheet is, move some columns of a single row to another row based on some criteria, and leave the older rows clear of content.
To put it other way, I check at which row columns B, C and H (let's call this row N° '3') match exactly with values at columns B, C and N (let's call this row N° '9'). Then I need to move information from J9:N9 to J3:N3.

So this is the code I've come up with. Problem is, at the end no changes are being made to the spreadsheet nor the 'rows' array when I log it.

````
function reordenarFacturas(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AP que esperan');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //get the last Row with values
  var filteredArray = [];

  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // get data as an array
  const nombresAP = sheet.getSheetValues(3,2,lastRow-2,2); //get columns 2 and 3 as an array

  //Clean nombresAP array from special characters so that later filterLogic works correctly (not using filter anymore, but still wanted to clear names list).
  for (h=0; h<lastRow-2; h++){ //rows
    for(j=0; j<2;j++){ //columns
      nombresAP[h][j] = nombresAP[h][j].toString().toUpperCase();
      nombresAP[h][j] = nombresAP[h][j].toString().replace(/á/ig, "A");
      nombresAP[h][j] = nombresAP[h][j].toString().replace(/é/ig, "E");
      nombresAP[h][j] = nombresAP[h][j].toString().replace(/í/ig, "I");
      nombresAP[h][j] = nombresAP[h][j].toString().replace(/ó/ig, "O");
      nombresAP[h][j] = nombresAP[h][j].toString().replace(/ú/ig, "U");
      nombresAP[h][j] = nombresAP[h][j].toString().replace("  ", " ");
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange("B3:C" + lastRow).setValues(nombresAP);
  //End of the cleaning section


  //NOT IN USE CURRENTLY, SAVED JUST IN CASE
  //Filterlogic works as a way to input several parameters to the filter method used below (now erased).
  /*
  var filterLogic = function(item){ //function to pass filter data later
    if (item[1] === apellidoAP && item[2] === nombreAP && item[7] === periodoFacturado){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
  */


  //Here I check whether certain columns have different values. If they do, then I retrieve some values on variables and push them to an array for later use.
  for (var h = 2; h<lastRow; h++){ // h starts at 2 because data starts at row N° 3
    if (rows[h][9] == '') continue; // If cells on this columns are empty, I don't need the row and can evaluate the next
    else if (rows[h][7] != rows[h][13]){  // If this two different cells of the same row have different values, I then
    //assign some data to variables, for later filtering other rows with said data

      var apellidoAP = rows[h][1];
      var nombreAP = rows[h][2];
      var periodoInformado = rows[h][7];
      var factura = rows[h][9];
      var fechaFactura = rows[h][10];
      var nroFactura = rows[h][11];
      var montoFactura = rows[h][12];
      var periodoFacturado = rows[h][13];

      filteredArray.push([[apellidoAP], [nombreAP], [periodoFacturado], [factura], [fechaFactura], [nroFactura], [montoFactura], [periodoFacturado]]);

      // Here I'm 'cleaning' some fields in the rows where I've found the differences (doesn't seem to be working)
      rows[h][9] == '';
      rows[h][10] == '';
      rows[h][11] == '';
      rows[h][12] == '';
      rows[h][13] == '';
    }
  }


  //And finally here, I check whether some filteredArray values match some values in the 'rows' array. If they do match, then I replace some more values in rows array with values from filteredArray. This doesn't seem to be working either.
  for (p = 2; p<rows.length; p++){
    for (r = 0; r<filteredArray.length; r++){
      if (rows[p][1] == filteredArray [r][0] && rows[p][2] == filteredArray[r][1] && rows[p][7] == filteredArray[r][2]){
        
        
        rows[p][9] == filteredArray[r][3];
        rows[p][10] == filteredArray[r][4];
        rows[p][11] == filteredArray[r][5];
        rows[p][12] == filteredArray[r][6];
        rows[p][13] == filteredArray[r][7];
      

      }
    }
  }
  
  //Finally I set rows back at the spreadsheet with all changes made, but no changes are shown in the spreadsheet once the script ends running.
  sheet.getRange("A1:U" + lastRow).setValues(rows);

}   
```
````

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in grreater detail.  I'd be glad to help if I don't have to read your code

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expected as the image?